# Compiling lua module for embedded interpreter

Tags: c++, dll, lua, mingw

I have a lua interpreter, which is embedded in the exe, Lua 5.1.5, x64. There are no sources for the exe. I can freely interact with it by providing .lua scripts, but I want to use my own C modules. There is no lua.dll or any similar modules along with exe, so I cannot build a dll. When I build the module using lua libraries from official site, compilation works fine, but I have to provide lua5.1.dll along with my module to be able to load it. After requiring, application hangs (probably because of conflict between internal lua functions and that lua5.1.dll).

I am using mingw64, compilation options:

```
gcc test.cpp -c
gcc -O -shared -o test.dll test.o -L ..\lua51_64\ -llua5.1
```

I cannot build the module without linking lua5.1.dll.

Is it possible to build a C module for lua so the module would use lua functions from the exe, not from standalone dll?

Comment: You may compile and link static. I had used from borland, microsoft compilers and work very well.

Comment: compile as a static library (.a) as suggested.

Comment: It definitely changed something, now my application crashes with bex64 error - something about DEP, even though I have DEP disabled. Thanks for the advice.